# SQL insert query throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is how my table looks like

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tdn_Winners]    Script Date: 08/12/2016 18:55:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tdn_Winners](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberId] [int] NULL,
    [PrizeNodeId] [int] NULL,
    [CampaignNodeId] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TND_Winners] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And I am inserting some values to this table like this

```
        string insertquery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tdn_Winners] ([MemberId] ,
    [PrizeNodeId] ,[CampaignNodeId] ,[TransactionId])  VALUES(@MemberId, 
    @PrizeNodeId, @CampaignNodeId, @TransactionId";


                int rowsAffected = sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(insertquery, 
sqlHelper.CreateParameter(parameterName: "@MemberId", value: 1), 
sqlHelper.CreateParameter(parameterName: "@PrizeNodeId", value: 1),
sqlHelper.CreateParameter(parameterName: 
"@CampaignNodeId",value: 1), sqlHelper.CreateParameter(parameterName: 
"@TransactionId", value: 1));
```

Everything looks ok to me, But this throws an error like this

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@TransactionId'.

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You forgot closing ")" in your command.

Comment: Your insert command is missing a closing parenthesis at the end `)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing closing bracket:

```
 string insertquery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tdn_Winners] ([MemberId] ,
[PrizeNodeId] ,[CampaignNodeId] ,[TransactionId])  VALUES(@MemberId, 
@PrizeNodeId, @CampaignNodeId, @TransactionId)";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are forgot to close the bracket.

> VALUES(@MemberId, @PrizeNodeId, @CampaignNodeId, @TransactionId`)`";

Answer (score 0):

The closing bracket after `@TransactionId` was missing.

Add it and retry. It should work.

```
   "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tdn_Winners] (
    [MemberId] ,
    [PrizeNodeId] ,
    [CampaignNodeId] ,
    [TransactionId]) 
     VALUES(
       @MemberId, 
       @PrizeNodeId, 
       @CampaignNodeId,
       @TransactionId)";
```